# Linear Algebra Standard Basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Question]

I have no idea what to do in this question, other then the fact that the formula $T$ is suppose to have some kind of $x$, $y$, $z$.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: Here's a hint to clarify your understanding of what is being asked. The "formula" is a formula in $X$, not in $x$, $y$, and $z$. The "formula" is a mathematical expression where you will input _vectors_ into where the place-holder $X$ is. For a  _vector_ $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what does $T$ "do" to that vector $X$? You know what it does to $E_1$, $E_2$, and $E_3$, and you know that $T$ is linear so...

Comment: Anyone know where I can read about this?

Comment: Try the exact same book where this problem was scanned from?

Comment: @alex.jordan Where does the question say that $T$ is linear?

Comment: @Daryl I guess it does not say that, unless in this book's language it is implied by the word "transformation". If it is allowed to be any old transformation, the problem makes no sense. Plus this just looks like a basic linear algebra exercise. Is this not homework from a linear algebra class? OP didn't answer that question.

Comment: The book does not state anything about this, if it did, i wouldn't be asking it on here, anyway I got the answer, thanks for everyone support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard basis is $E_1 = (1,0,0)$, $E_2 = (0,1,0)$, and $E_3 = (0,0,1)$. So if $X = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, it has the form $$X = (x,y,z) = x(1,0,0) + y(0,1,0) + z(0,0,1) =  x E_1 + y E_2 + z E_3.$$
Now use linearity of $T$ (which says $T(aX + bY) = aT(X) + bT(Y)$ for any numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and vectors $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and this extends to any finite sum of vectors) to get
$$
T(X) = T(xE_1 + y E_2 + z E_3) = xT(E_1) + yT(E_2) + zT(E_3).
$$
You are given $T(E_1)$, $T(E_2)$, and $T(E_3)$, so substitute in to get the answer.

Comment: While it is an appropriate assumption given the question, it does not explicitly state that $T$ is a **linear** transformation!, simply a transformation.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that too! I have no idea what to do though if it isn't linear. I guess it's up to OP to decide if this answer is useful after looking through the book for appropriate definitions and context.

Answer (score -1):

Use matrix, this application would not be more than the multiplication of the transpose of the image, ie, the matrix of T in the canonical bases. Where E is the canonical base, TE = Im (T). Note that the transpose of the canonical is herself. It is relatively simple, just imagine what their eyes are two dimensions and the third touch, movement, ie move your body is a linear application from R3 to R3, if you cut the arm of R3 to R2. The first thing is to understand what is the linear algebra. They are rotations of a abelian body relative origin. Body parallel to that form the space, which is always a abelian because infinite body is always finite. Poincare you recommend reading her books disclosure abstracion to understand mathematics. We facilitate life. Translations of google